# Sorting Dynamic Array With Data File

Tags: c++

I have an assignment in which I have to read from a file called ("random.txt") output the total and copy the file into an array dynamically. Then sort the values in the file.

Up until line 20 my programs runs fine and outputs my total values as well as all the numbers in file.

Line 21 onward also runs but then it doesn't output the total I had in line 20 when I run it and it also doesn't display the values in order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream fin;
  int n=0;
  double temp;
  fin.open("data.txt");
  fin>>temp;
  while(fin)
  {
      n++;
      fin>>temp;
      cout<<temp<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"Total:"<<n<<endl;
  fin.close(); //Program run fine up to here.
  fin.open("data.txt");
  double *A;
  A=new double[n];
  for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    for (int j=i;j<n;j++)
    if (A[i]>A[j])
    {
      int temp=A[i];
      A[i]=A[j];
      A[j]=temp;
    }
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      while(fin)
      {
          n++;
          fin>>A[i];
          cout<<"Array:"<<A[i]<<endl;//Program runs up to here as well but 
                                     //but now doesn't print out the total I          
                                     //had in my program above and just 
                                     //prints A[i] and its not even sorted. 

      }

  }
  fin.close();
}
```

I know I have a lot of errors, I'm very new to c++ so I'm still trying to learn. To be quite honest I don't know what I'm doing starting from line 32. I understand that I sorted my array from 24-31, but I don't know how to read my file into my array or how to format it.

Comment: `while(fin)` , and `fin>>A[i];`, and `n++`. - *none* of that should be in the last for-loop. You've already read the data and sorted it. Just dump it out. That last for-loop should have **one** line in it.

Comment: So I should just get rid of the while loop in my for loop? like this:

Comment: I re-edited my official post so can you please check that. now when I cout the value of A[i] its just printing out a bunch of zeros instead of numbers

Comment: I think I understand what you were trying to do. Obviously you need to load `A` with data, but it looks like you were doing it in the wrong place. After allocating `A` but *before* entering your nested `for` loop for sorting, move your recently deleted while-loop and load `A` with file values *there*. I.e between the allocation and the actual sort operation. Btw, you should NOT be changing `n` once you've established the size.

Comment: Don't edit the question's code further, so we aren't shooting at a moving target. ;)

Comment: @JonnyD The original post is what the OP had, and had problems with. I rolled back to the origin. Hopefully it stays now.

Answer (score 1):

Your array load is in the wrong location. It should be before the sort, but after the allocation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("data.txt");
    double temp;
    size_t n = 0;

    while(fin >> temp)
    {
        std::cout << temp << ' ';
        ++n;
    }
    std::cout << "Total: "<< n << endl;

    fin.close();

    if (n > 0)
    {
        fin.open("data.txt");

        double *A = new double[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n && fin >> A[i]; ++i);

        fin.close();

        for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            for (int j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                if (A[i]>A[j])
                {
                    int temp=A[i];
                    A[i]=A[j];
                    A[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            cout << "Array[" << i << "]: " << A[i] << endl;

        delete [] A;
    }
}
```

---

Honestly, there are **much** better ways to do this. Using the standard library containers, this entire menagerie is reduced to...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("data.txt");

    std::vector<double> A{
        std::istream_iterator<double>(fin),
        std::istream_iterator<double>() };

    std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A));

    for (auto x : A)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand now basically it was the location of my loop that was in the wrong place.Thanks a lot for the answer in code I can see my mistakes a lot clearer. So are the two codes you presented outputting the same thing but the second one you show is a lot quicker but I have not learned to use that in class yet. Do you mind explaining to me what it does by putting std::ifstream fin("data.txt") or by putting std:: in front of most of the stuff anyway like you have shown in your interpretation of the code.

Comment: @AdnanSheikh it *is* doable to insert them while sorting; its just a different algorithm (one such example is a modified aptly named *insertion sort*). I encourage you to look at the second example and spend some time researching the classes used therein. It will ultimately be worth it, believe me. Once you read more about them, it will really begin to gel.

Comment: I tried running the first code you displayed and it seems to be running but it's just printing the temp and total but not the array A[i] as well as it being sorted. Do you have any ideas why? Also can I ask why the file was closed at line 25 because should it not have been closed at the end?

Comment: Ok I'll definitely look into your second code and try to understand how it works. It seems to have made things a lot simpler. I'll look into working with vectors and iterators as you've shown. Just have to make sure my professor wouldn't mind me using things we haven't learned how to do yet.

Comment: @AdnanSheikh Duh. sry. Updated the source. that `std::cin >> A[i]` should be `fin >> A[i]`. Was testing it from the console. My bad. change that. should work.

Comment: Okay thanks it seemed to work not but now its not printing the total amount of values we had cout in the beginning of the program. Is there  a way to run both of them? Also the values are in order but once comparing the numbers I ran the first time using the std::cin>> A[i] compared to fin>> A[i] the some values are completely different from each other. I wish there was a way I could show you the the results of my output so it would be easier for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values to the elements of A before you can sort or read from A!

Comment: That is due to a recently deleted improperly placed while-loop. The original post did so, but in the wrong place. Rolling it back.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort in lines 24-31 is misplaced. `A` is defined on lines 22 and 23 but never initialized. I think you meant to read it from `data.txt` after reopening on line 21 but you did not.